# Azure ML Studio - How to merge/concatenate columns

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Which module in Azure ML Studio I should use to merge (concatenate) some three columns into another column (already existing). I am using [SMS Spam Collection Dataset from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/sms-spam-collection-dataset), in which CSV file should contain only 2 columns: v1 and v2. However, in some rows part of content from v2 went to Column 2, Column 3 and Column 4. So, how I can merge Column 2, Column 3 and Column 4 into (with) column v2?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Text to columns" in reverse mode in a way.
Please refer the article [here](https://gallery.azure.ai/CustomModule/Concatenate-Columns-1)